# PL Sql select column values where it doesnt exist in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below two tables in Oracle.

[image]

I have two requests:

1. I want to select all rows from **CONSIGNMENT_NO** column in **TABLE_1** that **TABLE_2** doesn’t have, which in this case at **TABLE_1** column 1 row 5
2. I want to select all above rows where **DEMAN_DATE** & **MANIFEST_DATE** is equal

I am using below code which is not working properly:

```
select distinct consignment_no from table_1 a
where not exists (select  b.consignment_no from table_2 b where trunc(a.deman_date)='&dat' and trunc(b.manifest_date)='&dat')
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, you have conflicting requirements.  You want records from table one that do not exits in table two.  With this scenario how would you ever have a condition where deman_date = manifest date?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t
       AS (SELECT   *
             FROM   tbl1
            WHERE   consignment_no NOT IN (SELECT   consignment_no FROM tbl2))
SELECT   tbl2.*
  FROM   t, tbl2
 WHERE   t.deman_date = tbl2.manifest_date;
```

here is the whole thing with create table statements....

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
AS
   SELECT   501000000 AS consignment_no,
            TO_DATE ('15/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS deman_date
     FROM   DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT   501000000, TO_DATE ('15/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT   501000000, TO_DATE ('15/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT   501000001, TO_DATE ('16/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT   501000002, TO_DATE ('16/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tbl2
AS
   SELECT   501000000 AS consignment_no,
            TO_DATE ('15/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS manifest_date
     FROM   DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT   501000001, TO_DATE ('16/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL;

WITH t
       AS (SELECT   *
             FROM   tbl1
            WHERE   consignment_no NOT IN (SELECT   consignment_no FROM tbl2))
SELECT   tbl2.*
  FROM   t, tbl2
 WHERE   t.deman_date = tbl2.manifest_date;
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of using the With T to make inline views

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understood you question but:

Select * from table_1 minus table_2

--In case you want distict values

Select distinct * from table_1 minus table_2

-- you can SELECT just one column in case you need

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can do this with an outer join and return the ones where Table 2 returns a null.

For 2, I assume that is a separate query you want. For that, a simple inner join will work.

If that isn't a separate query you want, then that's contradicting, you will never return any rows. You can't have a matching row in Table 2 if what you originally start with is all rows from Table 1 that aren't in Table 2.

Comment: For 2, is not a separate query actually I separate it for easily to understand.

Comment: Then your requirements don't make sense. They contradict. You can't have that in one query. Please read the last paragraph in my response.